# MySql JSON query between a range

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-8.0

I have a table `card_percentage`, with DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE card_percentage
(
    id   int UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    jdoc json NULL
);
```

It has one row of data

```
id | jdoc
------------ 
 1 | {"AMXC": [{"enabled": "y", "bank_code": "AMXC", "max_amount": 99999999.99, "min_amount": 0.0, "percentage": 2.5}], "VISA": [{"enabled": "y", "bank_code": "VISA", "max_amount": 1999.99, "min_amount": 0.0, "percentage": 2.8}, {"enabled": "y", "bank_code": "VISA", "max_amount": 99999999.99, "min_amount": 2000.0, "percentage": 1.8}]}
```

Beautified JSON for readability

```
{
  "AMXC": [
    {
      "enabled": "y",
      "bank_code": "AMXC",
      "min_amount": 0.0,
      "max_amount": 99999999.99,
      "percentage": 2.5
    }
  ],
  "VISA": [
    {
      "enabled": "y",
      "bank_code": "VISA",
      "min_amount": 0.0,
      "max_amount": 1999.99,
      "percentage": 2.8
    },
    {
      "enabled": "y",
      "bank_code": "VISA",
      "min_amount": 2000.0,
      "max_amount": 99999999.99,
      "percentage": 1.8
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to select `percentage` for `VISA` when amount `200` is between `min_amount` and `max_amount`. For this I am using following query but it is giving nothing in result set.

```
SELECT id,
       jdoc -> '$.VISA[*].percentage' percentage
FROM card_percentage
WHERE id = 1
  AND jdoc -> '$.VISA[*].min_amount' <= 200
  AND jdoc -> '$.VISA[*].max_amount' >= 200
;
```

Comment: See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4869abf90d78494bc1efeca977ddadbc - it displays your problem source. You must convert your JSON to a table (use [JSON_TABLE() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html)).

Comment: Please show us the results that you want for this sample data.

Comment: @GMB of course he wants to get a row with the values of `(1, 2.8)`...

Comment: @Akina, based on your inputs, I tried JSON_TABLE, its really interesting. Let me post an Answer with more details.

Comment: Why "let"? this is the best choice...

Comment: I meant "I will add an answer", "Let me" is used as "figure of speech". Thanks a lot for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok based on @Akina's comment about using JSON_TABLE, I did further research.

Following is my query, which works really well.

```
SELECT id, jdoc.percentage
FROM card_percentage, JSON_TABLE(
             jdoc,
             '$.VISA[*]'
             COLUMNS (
                 rowid FOR ORDINALITY,
                 enabled VARCHAR(1) PATH '$.enabled' DEFAULT '"n"' ON EMPTY DEFAULT '"n"' ON ERROR,
                 bank_code VARCHAR(4) PATH '$.bank_code' DEFAULT '"NCOD"' ON EMPTY ,
                 min_amount INT PATH '$.min_amount' DEFAULT '0' ON EMPTY ,
                 max_amount INT PATH '$.max_amount' DEFAULT '0' ON EMPTY ,
                 percentage DECIMAL(10, 2) PATH '$.percentage' DEFAULT '0' ON EMPTY DEFAULT '0' ON ERROR
                 )
         ) AS jdoc
WHERE jdoc.min_amount <= 200
  AND jdoc.max_amount >= 200
;
```

To get this working, this article ["JSON_TABLE – The Best of Both Worlds"](https://mysqlserverteam.com/json_table-the-best-of-both-worlds/) really helped.

Comment: What is the profit in parsing columns which are not used? rowid, enabled, bank_code...

Comment: Of course only min_amount, max_amount and percentage are enough for my purpose, I am using only those three column in my production code. I wanted to highlight that how `'"n"'` is put in default, that is important as `'n'` won't work.